# NextJS "Caching failed for pack [...] no such file or directory"

Tags: webpack, next.js

I am repeatedly getting the same error when I'm using hot-reloading to tweak the css in nextjs while running on npm run dev.

The problem fixes itself when I remove the `.next` folder and re-run `npm run dev` as shown in other threads. However, the same error still re-appears after a while which makes the development cycle very annoying. Is this the problem of my webpack?

Main error message:

```
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/server-development/1.pack.gz'
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/4.pack.gz'
```

[image]

Full Stack Trace:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'
}
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'
}
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'
}
 ⨯ unhandledRejection: [Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'] {
  errno: -2,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'
}
<w> [webpack.cache.PackFileCacheStrategy] Caching failed for pack: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/cache/webpack/client-development/2.pack.gz'




 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/server/app/not-found.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at requirePage (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js:109:84)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:59:84
    at async loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:59:26)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:666:36) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ]
}


 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/server/app/not-found_client-reference-manifest.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at loadClientReferenceManifest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:43:72)
    at loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:65:29)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:666:36)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponents (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:543:20)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1926:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:851:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:748:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ]
}
 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/server/app/not-found_client-reference-manifest.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at loadClientReferenceManifest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:43:72)
    at loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:65:29)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:666:36)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponents (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:543:20)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1926:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:851:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:748:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ]
}
 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/server/app/not-found_client-reference-manifest.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at loadClientReferenceManifest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:43:72)
    at loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:65:29)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:666:36)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponents (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:543:20)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1926:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:851:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:748:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ]
}
 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/server/app/not-found_client-reference-manifest.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at loadClientReferenceManifest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:43:72)
    at loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:65:29)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:666:36)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponents (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:543:20)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1926:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:851:25)
    at async NextNodeServer.handleCatchallRenderRequest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:266:17)
    at async DevServer.handleRequestImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:748:17) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ]
}
 ⨯ Error: Cannot find module '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/.next/server/app/not-found_client-reference-manifest.js'
Require stack:
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js
- /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1072:15)
    at /Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:54:36
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:925:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1139:19)
    at mod.require (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/require-hook.js:64:28)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:121:18)
    at loadClientReferenceManifest (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:43:72)
    at loadComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js:65:29)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponentsImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/next-server.js:666:36)
    at async DevServer.findPageComponents (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/next-dev-server.js:543:20)
    at async DevServer.renderErrorToResponseImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1926:30)
    at async pipe.req.req (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:1892:30)
    at async DevServer.pipeImpl (/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/base-server.js:851:25) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/load-components.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/build/utils.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-middleware.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/dev/hot-reloader-webpack.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-utils/setup-dev-bundler.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/router-server.js',
    '/Users/tylerkim/Documents/Scraft/scraft-main/node_modules/next/dist/server/lib/start-server.js'
  ]
}
```